Expo web app - o.turbomoduleregistry is undefined
I'm running into the following JS console error when trying to run Expo app for the web on my local machine. I am able to run for iOS and Android without any issues.
Uncaught TypeError: o.TurboModuleRegistry is undefined
    <anonymous> http://localhost:3000/_expo/static/js/web/AppEntry-f1a70a6051ce10b32203e5883d082d48.js:696

I am building using
npx expo export -p web 
npx serve dist --single

Everything builds fine. I have dist/index.html as well as /_expo/... generated from the build and there are no warnings/errors in CLI.
Here is my relevant app.json
"web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png",
      "bundler": "metro"
},

